# Restarting IIS website, copying new files with external program

Tags: c#, .net, iis, permissions, admin

I have website (.net core 3.1) up on IIS (v10) on Windows (10)
**website is calling external .exe that will stop IIS website (caller website)**, copy new files to iis website folder and start the site again. Problem is, when i stop website from external exe it doesn't shut down the website like admin does, then external program can't copy new files to website folder.

When i stop website manually i can copy and overwrite files it works as it should

Here is a snipped of website code that is calling external .exe:

```
            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:UpdaterPath");
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.Start();
            }
```

here is a snippet of my external exe code:

```
                ServerManager server = new ServerManager();
                var site = server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == _settings.WebsiteName);
                if (site != null)
                {
                 
                    //Cloning old version to backup
                    Log($"Copying old files to backup...");
                    CloneDirectory(_settings.WebsitePath, Path.Combine(_settings.BackupPath, _settings.WebsiteName));

                    //Copying new version to working dir
                    //if(!Directory.Exists(temp_folder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(temp_folder);
                    Log($"Extracting new files...");
                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(temp_zip, temp_folder, true);

                    Log($"Stopping {_settings.WebsiteName}...");
                    site.Stop();



                    Log($"Copying new files...");
                    CloneDirectory(Path.Combine(_settings.FilesPath, "temp"), _settings.WebsitePath);

                    Log($"Starting {_settings.WebsiteName}...");
                    site.Start();


                    if (site.State == ObjectState.Started)
                    {
                                          
           
          server.ApplicationPools[site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName].Recycle();
                        
                    }

                }
```

CloneDirectory() just copies/overwrites files recursively.
I've tried stoping website pool, recycling, server.CommitChanges(), but nothing works because main dll files with real changes to website can't be copied because **

> access is denied

**
this all works fine when i call exe as administrator

I've tried giving folder/files user privileges to IIS_IUSRS and my website default pool
I've tried giving website physical path credentials as administrator
I've tried giving website pool privileges identity set to admin acc, or NetworkService, LocalService
basically any combo i can think off
what i noticed is when i stop app pool in my exe it stops working after a few seconds

I assume there is a problem with privileges (cant stop iis, copy files etc)

Comment: i would like to inform you that without admin privilege you can not start of stop iis site or service, here you can check the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#starting-and-stopping-sites

Comment: In short, any API around `ServerManager` requires administrator permissions to manipulate IIS components (start/stop sites for example). Thus, unless you run your web site under an admin account, the mechanism you describe above won't work. You shouldn't run a site as admin either (unless really necessary and you are willing to take the risks).